# How to apply to new data on tkinter's canvas

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I have been working on a Gui-based program using Tkinter. It needs data to display and there are a lot of different data. I tried to do it, but it did not show the right result. I mean, it cannot display other datasets and it just displays the first dataset.

Simply, its procedure is as following:

1. Load 1st data
2. Display on canvas
3. Load another data
4. Display on canvas, but it shows the first data.

Please give me some hints, comments, and help.

Thank you, guys.

Comment: Would you mind showing the code that you are current using?

Comment: It is impossible to find a logic bug like this without seeing your actual code.

Comment: actual code is pretty complicated and long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interest of saving time and just giving an idea, I have just pulled this out from some code hoping it might help you ...

```
class SubWindow:

    def change(self):
        self.s1Var.set("new1")

    def createWidgets(self, root):
        self.s1Var = StringVar(); self.s1Var.set("string1")

        self.s1Label = Label(root,textvariable=self.s1Var)
        self.s1Label.grid(row=0, column=5)

        self.changeButton = Button(root, text="Change", command=self.change)
        self.changeButton.grid(row=9, column=7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code to display the data is correct, the only conclusion I can draw is that either you "load another data" function isn't actually loading anything, or your "display on canvas" code is not being given tne newly loaded data.

The other possibility is that there is an error in your drawing code that is getting ignored.